# hector_quadrotor_demo goes unstable when robot gets high enough

Tags: physics

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Related to a ros package, so originally asked on [answers.ros](http://answers.ros.org/question/49960/unstable-hector_quadrotor-above-a-given-height/).. but can anyone see a reason why a simulation would become unstable and subsequently crash because of the position of a robot in Gazebo?
See [video](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9Gk5iW1PiEoNl9KQ25rR0dIRzA/preview) and [another video here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9Gk5iW1PiEoMWNhTFNUaHQ3Wjg/preview).

For reference in this is with `roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo outdoor_flight_gazebo.launch` and `rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[0,0,0.1]' '[0,0,0]'`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/466/hector_quadrotor_demo-goes-unstable-when-robot-gets-high-enough../) by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 319 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-12-10**:
Which version of Gazebo are you using?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-11**:
Gazebo 1.6.16 (from ubuntu precise ros-fuerte packages)

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-12-12**:
Just for clarity, the above version number is not the version of Gazebo. That is the version of the ROS simulator_gazebo package. The actual Gazebo version is 1.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So far the answer seems related to the controller for the quadrotor.. the problem only appears to occur if both the imuTopic and the stateTopic are subscribed.

Still not sure why.. but when the controller reads data directly from gazebo `link->GetWorldPose()` and `link->GetWorldLinearVel()` instead of subscribing to the data that gazebo is publishing, the model is much more well behaved.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-13**:
Both of those topics are set by default in the quadrobor ubuntu debs.